# Different Edit queues for formatting/language edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Anything in the queue that is not a simple improvement of language or formatting would need to be rejected.

It would also be super easy to make audits for this review-queue,
because the definition is pretty clear cut,
that means you could make a high% of audits in order to ensure that the feature isn't used as a replacement or the 3k edit queue.

It would also lower the load on the 3k edit queue.

Comment: so essentially... a trivial edit queue ... when I figure trivial edits are discouraged?

Comment: Why trivial ? I mean, the author could have severe grammar or formatting issues, in which case the edit would still be valid.

Answer (score 5):

That what suggested edits are *already* for.  Edits of others' posts are there to improve the presentation of posts, not to change the underlying meaning of the posts; edits that change the underlying meaning *already merit rejection*.

Answer (score 1):

You should not make (just) trivial edits. Of course, small edits can be done but only when you have enough reputation. You should always edit as much as possible. Just making trivial exits when there is more you could have done is not what we expect.

I don't know why you are so eager on lowering the load on the suggested edit queue. You are fixing the wrong thing. The community might need to be encouraged to review more frequently if the queue is full too often.

Comment: The inherent design flaw is, that users below 2k can only edit when the review-queue isn't full and can't review, and user above 2k can always edit and are the only ones who can review the "edit"-queue.

That means the only ones who aren't aware of the problem, are the only ones who can solve it.

Comment: The proposal isn't asking for a queue for trivial edits, just a queue for edits that are only changing the presentation of the post.  Edits can only be improving the presentation and yet be *very* substantial.